# How could Finn know about Han Solo, given Finn's upbringing?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey, star-wars-finn, han-solo

In *The Force Awakens*, we learn that

1. Luke has vanished and is now the stuff of myth and legend
2. Han also vanished from the spotlight, having left the Republic/Resistance and is living on the DL as a smuggler or something

**How could Finn identify Han Solo as a war hero of the Galactic Civil War if  he was raised from (near) infancy by the First Order?** Related sub-question: Shouldn't Han also be the stuff of myth and legend now as well? (e.g. If Rey thought Luke was just a myth, shouldn't she think the same of Han?)

Comment: giving solo's involvement in blow up giant space stations, i wonder if the first order didnt have a poster, if you see this man, your ship may already be blowing up

Comment: @Himarm Maybe from the same media campaign that taught him all about rathtars - exotic wildlife, galactic terrorists, and other threats to the Order.

Comment: Rey is an unreliable narrator in a sense because we don't know anything about her background. First, living on a backwater, alone from early childhood renders her education probably somewhat limited. Not to mention who knows what kind of actual Sith / Jedi memory games have been played on her. In other words, Rey doesn't know what she knows and what she doesn't know. She's a galactic blank slate

Comment: [Maybe the First Order gave stormtrooprs space-packs of playing cards of famous space-terrorists and traitors against the galactic empire to ensure they recognised them?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most-wanted_Iraqi_playing_cards)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finn has apparently had access to *entertainment programmes* (of a historical nature) as well as the more mundane First-Order weapons and tactical training.

> As madness ebbed and surged around him, he wandered through the
> village, **feeling himself more a participant in a historical drama than
> in an actual battle.** The horrific and all too common red stains on the
> ground contradicted his denial. This wasn’t like his training at all,
> he told himself numbly. Unlike in simulations, reality bled.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

What's most interesting is that in his personal study of "ancient history" he clearly views the heroes as being the Rebellion, not the Empire. An early (and evidently overlooked) seed of his own future rebellious nature.

> “Huh?” If he had been bemused before, Finn was now thoroughly bewildered. Without thinking, he addressed the shaggy mass lumbering along in front of him.   **“Wasn’t he a war hero? In the fight against the Old Empire?”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

There's also some indication that Han's activities may have been covered as part of Finn's overall combat training, especially since Han was involved in several *iconic* battles against the Empire.

> For the better part of a week, **they studied and were repeatedly tested
> on different historical battles, many from the Clone Wars, some even
> earlier.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Before the Awakening](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Before_the_Awakening)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 5):

First Order rose from the ashes of the empire. Everything that happened, was passed on to the new "employees". Anything about Han, Leia, Rebels, Luke; all enemies of the new First Order/formerly the Empire would have been ingrained the troopers heads.

Remember in Attack of the Clones-while describing what clones are capable of, the director told Obi-Wan that his clones were trained from birth, to obey any order without question. Even though the new stormtroopers aren't clones, they would need to be taught everything from the First Order's point of view.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but a citation would improve your answer.